# How to let JavaScript display a sign but calculate meanwhile with numbers

Tags: javascript, html

I am coding a calculator and I am encountered a challenge. I want that when the user is for a example pressing the π button that JavaScript is displaying the π sign in innerHTML but calculating in the background with the associated numbers viz 3.141...  The same when pressing the faculty sign, JavaScript should display only the exclamation mark after a number. Or by pressing the e button, JavaScript should display the e in innerHTML but calculate in the background with the associated numbers. How can I do this?

````html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

    <script>
function appendOperation(operation) {
    document.getElementById("resultArea").innerHTML +=operation;
};

function calculateResult() {
    let container = document.getElementById('resultArea');
    let result = container.innerHTML;
    container.innerHTML = eval(result);
};

function deleteLast() {
let container = document.getElementById('resultArea');
if(container.innerHTML.endsWith(' ')) {
    container.innerHTML = container.innerHTML.slice(0, -3);
    } 
    else {
    container.innerHTML = container.innerHTML.slice(0, -1);
        }
};

function deleteContent() {
  document.getElementById('resultArea').innerHTML = "";
};

function Percent() {
 document.getElementById('resultArea').innerHTML = document.getElementById('resultArea').innerHTML / 100;

  
  
};
 
function changingPresign() {
        value = eval(document.getElementById('resultArea').innerHTML* (-1)) ; 
        document.getElementById('resultArea').innerHTML = value; 
};



function squared() {
    let x = document.getElementById('resultArea')
    x.innerHTML = Math.pow(parseFloat(document.getElementById('resultArea').innerHTML), 2); // 
};      

function rooting() {
  document.getElementById('resultArea').innerHTML = Math.pow(parseFloat(document.getElementById('resultArea').innerHTML)
                                                            , 0.5);
};
/*
parseInt rundet eine Berechnung auf eine ganze Zahl, wobei ParseFloat das Ergebnis einer Berechnung auf Dezimalzahlen beruhen lassen kann.*/

function faculty() {
    let repetitions = 1;
    let increasment = 1;
    let input = document.getElementById('resultArea').innerHTML
    while(repetitions <= input) {
      
      increasment = increasment * repetitions;
      repetitions++;
    document.getElementById('resultArea').innerHTML = increasment
    } ;
};

function anyExponent() {
   exponent = prompt("Nennen Sie den Exponenten");
    document.getElementById('resultArea').innerHTML = Math.pow(parseFloat(document.getElementById('resultArea').innerHTML),exponent );
};

function eulerscheZahl() {
    document.getElementById('resultArea').innerHTML = Math.exp(document.getElementById('resultArea').innerHTML);
};

function Pi() {
    document.getElementById('resultArea').innerHTML += Math.PI
}
    </script>
</head>

<style>
body {
    background-color: black;
    font-family: 'Changa', sans-serif;
    margin: 0;
}

table {
    width: 100%;
    height: 70vh;
    background-color: rgb(30, 30, 30);
    color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
}

td {
  font-size: 30px;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: black;
}

td:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
}

.operation-button {
    color: white;
    background-color: rgb(10, 146, 187);
}

.operation-button:hover {
    background-color: rgb(6, 174, 225);
}

.changing-button {
    background-color: rgb(53, 53, 53);
    color: white;
}

.changing-button:hover {
    background-color: rgb(96, 93, 93);
}

.numbers:hover {
background-color: rgb(14, 13, 13);
}

#resultArea {
    height: 30vh;
    color: white;
    font-size: 64px;
    display:flex;
    justify-content: flex-end;
    align-items: flex-end;
    padding: 24px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    
    
}
#resultarea:hover {
    color: #0a92bb;
}

#brackets {
width: 25%;
}
</style>


<body>

    <div id="resultArea"></div>

    <table>
        <tr>

            <td onclick="changingPresign()" class="changing-button">±</td>
            <td onclick="Percent()" class="changing-button">%</td>
            <td onclick="squared()" class="changing-button">x²</td>
            <td onclick="appendOperation(' / ')" class="operation-button">÷</td>
            <td id="brackets" onclick="appendOperation('(')" class="changing-button">(</td>
            <td onclick="appendOperation(')')" class="changing-button">)</td>



        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td onclick="appendOperation(7)" class="numbers">7</td>
            <td onclick="appendOperation(8)" class="numbers">8</td>
            <td onclick="appendOperation(9)" class="numbers">9</td>
            <td onclick="appendOperation('*')" class="operation-button">×</td>
            <td onclick="rooting()" class="changing-button">√</td>
            <td onclick="eulerscheZahl()" class="changing-button">e</td> 

        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td onclick="appendOperation(4)" class="numbers">4</td>
            <td onclick="appendOperation(5)" class="numbers">5</td>
            <td onclick="appendOperation(6)" class="numbers">6</td>
            <td onclick="appendOperation('-')" class="operation-button">-</td>
            <td onclick="faculty()" class="changing-button">x!</td>
            <td onclick="anyExponent()" class="changing-button">xʸ</td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td onclick="appendOperation(1)" class="numbers">1</td>
            <td onclick="appendOperation(2)" class="numbers">2</td>
            <td onclick="appendOperation(3)" class="numbers">3</td>
            <td onclick="appendOperation('+')" class="operation-button">+</td>
            <td onclick="deleteContent()" class="changing-button">AC</td>
            <td onclick="Pi()" class="changing-button">π</td>

        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td onclick="appendOperation(0)" colspan="2" class="numbers">0</td>
            <td onclick="appendOperation('.')" class="numbers">,</td>
            <td onclick="calculateResult()" id="result" class="operation-button">=</td>
            <td onclick="deleteLast()" id="ac" class="changing-button">CE</td>
            <td onclick="Ans()" class = "changing-button">Ans</td>
        </tr>

    </table>

</body>

</html>
```
````

Comment: include the sign not inside the string but as a variable that you display in the end. Highly advice not to use `innerHTML` for security and performance reasons. A good alternative would be `textContent`

Comment: Thank you for your advices. Do you mean like this: function Pi(pi) {
    let pi = "π";
    document.getElementById('resultArea').innerHTML  += pi
    document.getElementById('resultArea').innerHTML = Math.PI 
    
} ?

Comment: So you only want to evaluate the expression when clicking `=`? What about `√`, would  you also want to just let the user type it (before) the relevant number, and `²` after the number, ...etc? Then this calculator really becomes a keyboard add-on to type special characters, and the `=` will be the only button that has some magic. Is my understanding right?

Comment: BTW, the `±` button produces `NaN` when the expression already has some operators in it.

Comment: I think you need to take a step back and first see if you want to make a typical calculator (that does not show operators, but applies them), or an expression builder that eventually can be evaluated. Mixing both concepts will feel odd.

Comment: First, thank you. It´s my first project therefore I am inexperienced. Yes my calculator should even display √  or  ². What I have to do to implement those capabilities and fix the bugg you mentioned?